# AWS Amplify send logs to Splunk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'd like to send Amplify monitoring data(access logs, metrics) to Splunk - this would be best case scenario. But for the beginning it would be ok if I could at least store them into another service like s3 or even grater to link it with CloudWatch, as I haven't found if those logs are somehow taken from CW log groups.
My question would be if there's a way to get those metrics outside of Amplify service?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way you can send CW logs to your 3rd Party Apps.

Two Major steps:

1. **Export CW logs to s3**.
2. **Configure lambda with s3 bucket** & write your logic to read & send logs to 3rd party apps every time a file is written on bucket.

**Cloudwatch allows you to export logs to s3.**

From [AWS docs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html)

> To export data to Amazon S3 using the CloudWatch console
>
> 1. Sign in as the IAM user that you created in Step 2: Create an IAM user
>    with full access to Amazon S3 and CloudWatch Logs.
> 2. Open the CloudWatch console at
>    https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.
> 3. In the navigation pane, **choose Log groups**.
> 4. On the Log Groups screen, **choose the name of the log group**.
> 5. Choose **Actions**, **Export data to Amazon S3**.
> 6. On the Export data to Amazon S3 screen, under Define data export, **set
>    the time range** for the data to export using From and To.
> 7. If your log group has multiple log streams, you can provide a log
>    stream prefix to **limit** the log group data to a specific stream. **Choose
>    Advanced**, and then for Stream prefix, **enter the log stream prefi**x.
> 8. Under Choose S3 bucket, **choose the account** associated with the Amazon
>    S3 bucket.
> 9. For S3 bucket name, **choose an Amazon S3 bucket**.
> 10. For S3 Bucket prefix, enter the randomly generated string that you
>     specified in the bucket policy.
> 11. **Choose Export to export your log data to Amazon S3**.
> 12. To view the status of the log data that you exported to Amazon S3,
>     **choose Actions** and then View all exports to Amazon S3.

Once you have exported logs into S3, You can setup simple S3 lambda trigger to read & send these logs to Third Party Applications(splunk in this case) using their APIs.

This way you'd also have saved logs in the S3 for future use or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I guess my main concern is how one could link Amplify access logs/metrics with CW ? How do you know which cw log group is referenced - this is what I couldn't find.

Comment: To be more precise, when I am in Metrics section from Amplify service and hover on a chart, then selecting "View Logs" - it goes directly in CW without showing a specific log group that is the source for this dashboard